# Compare two colums in two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two dataframes both containing a column name

Colums in dataframe 1 are
( idABT name    description price)

Colums in dataframe 2 are
( idBuy   name    description manufacturer    price)

There are some names in dataframe1 which are also found in dataframe2 how can i get th idABT and idBuy in another dataframe

Comment: hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. take some time to read the rules here [ask] and edit your answer in-line with the standard guidance here [mcve]

Comment: Do you need `idABT` and `idBUY` values for the rows that have the same `name`? If so, just join the two dataframes on the `name` column.

Comment: [The pandas documentation at this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two dataframes with the columns you describe,

```
import pandas
print(pandas.__version__)

df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'idABT':['A','F', 'H'], 
                        'name': ['B', 'G', 'I'], 
                        'description':['C','J','K'], 
                        'price':[1, 2, 3]})

df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'idBuy':['A', 'M','N'], 
                        'name': ['B', 'I', 'O'], 
                        'description':['C','P','Q'], 
                        'manufacturer':['E','X','Y'], 
                        'price':[5, 6, 7]})
```

You can merge the two dataframes using

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='name', right_on='name')
```